# Need help in ploting PSD(Power spectral density) on python

Tags: python

This is my code to plot a Power spectral density signal. I need some help as im having error coding in python.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
from scipy import signal

t=np.linspace(0,1,106)
Fs=1000
y=np.sin(2*math.pi*15*t) + np.sin(2*math.pi*30*t)
Y=fft(y,512)
f = np.arange(0,len(Y)-1)*(Fs-1)/len(Y)
P = abs(Y)*2/len(Y)
plt.plot(f,P)
plt.show()
```

This is the error i have when i try to run it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keehu\Desktop\trial.py", line 13, in <module>
    plt.plot(f,P)
  File "C:\Users\keehu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2761, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "C:\Users\keehu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1646, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\keehu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 216, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\keehu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 342, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (511,) and (512,)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `f` is of size `len(Y)-1` as you requested, but P has size `len(Y)`.

Answer (score 0):

The size of `f` is 511 and Y is 512. I have changed the code to solve that.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
from scipy import signal

t=np.linspace(0,1,106)
Fs=1000
y=np.sin(2*math.pi*15*t) + np.sin(2*math.pi*30*t)
Y=fft(y,512)
f = np.arange(0,len(Y))*(Fs-1)/len(Y) #changed here
P = abs(Y)*2/len(Y)
plt.plot(f,P)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

"*ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (511,) and (512,)*" means that your arrays, f and P don't have the same size. f is one element to small. Use:

```
f = np.arange(0,len(Y))*(Fs-1)/len(Y)
```